# PHP Selecting a single result

Tags: php, search

I created a PHP form which allows users to **Register and Log in**. Now I created another page named *View.php* that will *show all the registered users* in my `MySQL` database. The code I used was

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))...
```

and **it displayed all the users successfully**.

Now I created another PHP page which I named *profile.php*. I want to add a **link** from every result on *view.php* which will redirect to *profile.php?user=(their username)*. But I don't know how.

Comment: it's in http://pastebin.com/u4dNkaav :)

Comment: the $them I used was temporarily my own username so if I click the link it will always redirect to my data.. I really want it to like if I click the View Profile of "Bob", the php will redirect me to profile.php?user=bob... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
echo "<small><a href = 'profile.php?user=$them'>[View Profile]</a></small><br/>";
```

instead of using your fixed $them, just use $row['id']. Then you can fetch the user with that id in your profile.php file:

```
$id = $_GET['user'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where id = $id";
```

Note that this code is prone to sql injection. I only posted it to make the idea easier to understand. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

In your **view.php** considering that you have a column named 'username' , change the following :
please not, it's preferably to put the ID column If you want to put the id column, simply change the `$row['username']` to `$row['id']` and the same in the query in `profile.php`

```
<?php
...
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "---------------------<br/>";
                    echo "<b>".$row['fullname']."</b><br/>";
                    echo "<small><i>".$row['course']."</i></small><br/>";
                    echo "<small><a href = 'friends.php?user=".$row['username']."'>[View Profile]</a></small><br/>";
                    echo "---------------------<br/><br/>";
     
            }
     
    ?>
```

And in your
**profile.php**

```
<?php session_start();
 
        if($_SESSION['logged_in']==false) {
                header("Location:login.php");
        }
 
 
        include("header.php");
 
?>
 
<html>
<head>
        <title>View School-Mates</title>
</head>
        <body>
                <center>
                        <h1>My School-Mates</h1>
                        <small>View or Add them in your Trust List</small>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <hr>
                </center>
 
<?php
 try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_basic', "root", "");

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username= ?");
        if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['user']))) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                //here you will have your row with all your username data
            }
        }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
       
?>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Please read more about [PDO from here](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)  and [how to do connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) this is required because you get data from your $_GET variable, and thus you need to [avoid for sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Hopefully this is what you wanted, if not, please let me know so i can adjust the code

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the code you are using to achieve the result but having something like :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE id=$id";
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

This will filter out the profile page according to the user id